# CMake error with building opencv in CUDA_cufft_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)

Tags: opencv

I am using CMake3.7.2 to build opencv 3.2.0. The configuring process shows the error as follows:

CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND. Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:

```
CUDA_cufft_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "opencv_cudev" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/cudev
    linked by target "opencv_test_cudev" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/cudev/test
    linked by target "opencv_core" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/core
    linked by target "opencv_test_core" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/core
    linked by target "opencv_perf_core" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/core
    linked by target "opencv_test_cudaarithm" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/cudaarithm
    linked by target "opencv_cudaarithm" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/cudaarithm
    linked by target "opencv_cudaarithm" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/cudaarithm
    linked by target "opencv_perf_cudaarithm" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/cudaarithm
    linked by target "opencv_flann" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/flann
    linked by target "opencv_test_flann" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/flann
    linked by target "opencv_imgproc" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/imgproc
    linked by target "opencv_test_imgproc" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/imgproc
    linked by target "opencv_perf_imgproc" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/imgproc
    linked by target "opencv_test_ml" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/ml
    linked by target "opencv_ml" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/ml
    linked by target "opencv_test_video" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/video
    linked by target "opencv_video" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/video
    linked by target "opencv_perf_video" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/video
    linked by target "opencv_cudabgsegm" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/cudabgsegm
    linked by target "opencv_test_cudabgsegm" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/cudabgsegm
    linked by target "opencv_perf_cudabgsegm" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/cudabgsegm
    linked by target "opencv_cudafilters" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/cudafilters
    linked by target "opencv_test_cudafilters" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/cudafilters
    linked by target "opencv_perf_cudafilters" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/cudafilters
    linked by target "opencv_cudaimgproc" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/cudaimgproc
    linked by target "opencv_test_cudaimgproc" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/cudaimgproc
    linked by target "opencv_perf_cudaimgproc" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/cudaimgproc
    linked by target "opencv_perf_cudawarping" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/cudawarping
    linked by target "opencv_cudawarping" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/cudawarping
    linked by target "opencv_test_cudawarping" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/cudawarping
    linked by target "opencv_imgcodecs" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/imgcodecs
    linked by target "opencv_test_imgcodecs" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/imgcodecs
    linked by target "opencv_perf_imgcodecs" in directory C:/opencv-3.2/source/modules/imgcodecs
    linked by target "opencv_perf_photo" in directory 
    ..........
```

Comment: what is your OS and CUDA version? AFAIK cmake could not find some modules for CUDA 9.0

Comment: Which variables are set as not found, just `CUDA_cufft_LIBRARY` or other ones as well? how does your cmake output looks like (complete output)?

Comment: I use winds10 and Cuda8.0. The problem has been solved somehow, when I select vs2015-win64 as the complier instead of vs2015 in the configure prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting vs2015-win64 as the complier does solve my problem.